# Angular2 router.redirect not working

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have strange behavior with redirect function

The route is :

```
    {path:'order/:number/quotation/validate', component: OrderCreatedValidationMenuComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard]},
```

In HTML page, this works fine :

```
<a [routerLink]="['/order/' + order.number + '/quotation/validate']" >Quotation</a>
```

In the component, this isn't working :

```
import {Router} from "@angular/router";
...
this.router.navigate(['/order/' + this.order.number + '/quotation/validate']);
```

It redirects to:

```
http://localhost:4200/?param1=1&param2=1&param3=1#/order/161012-MM-4/quotation/validate
```

Comment: What about this - ['/order', this.order.number, 'quotation/validate']?

Comment: zone.js:355 Unhandled Promise rejection: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'order/161017-CIRB-1-TMP/quotation%2Fvalidate' ; Zone: angular ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'order/161017-CIRB-1-TMP/quotation%2Fvalidate'(…) Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'order/161017-CIRB-1-TMP/quotation%2Fvalidate'  => it replace '/' by '%2F'

Comment: Not able to redirect within angular 2 component ?